# Why can't I access header-field via $this->request->header('Authorization')?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to access the http-header field "Authorization" in CakePHP 2.5 during a CORS-Request from a mobile device with the following command:

```
$this->request->header('Authorization');
```

Which returns false. If the header is not present this is the expected result (see: [Docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#CakeRequest::header)). But the Devloper tools show the following request:

```
GET //api_customers/index.json HTTP/1.1
Host: aeap.localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://localhost:9000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 7_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11A465 Safari/9537.53
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImFkbWluX253In0.NszPvZauAWRq5GqqS70l_0UTkTCJoHkRWM8ZM8O0-fk
Referer: http://localhost:9000/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
```

So the header-field should be present and accessible. I can access the header-field "User-Agent" though. Can someone help me out here? What am I missing here?

**Edit**

When I access the headers of the request via plain [apache_request_headers()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php) the header seems to be present (loop output via CakeLog::debug):

```
2014-11-13 12:09:28 Debug: Host:aeap.localhost
2014-11-13 12:09:28 Debug: Connection:keep-alive
2014-11-13 12:09:28 Debug: Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
2014-11-13 12:09:28 Debug: Origin:http://localhost:9000
2014-11-13 12:09:28 Debug: User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 7_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11A465 Safari/9537.53
2014-11-13 12:09:28 Debug: Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, authorization
2014-11-13 12:09:28 Debug: Accept:*/*
2014-11-13 12:09:28 Debug: Referer:http://localhost:9000/
2014-11-13 12:09:28 Debug: Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
2014-11-13 12:09:28 Debug: Accept-Language:de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
2014-11-13 12:09:28 Debug: 
2014-11-13 12:09:28 Debug: Host:aeap.localhost
2014-11-13 12:09:28 Debug: Connection:keep-alive
2014-11-13 12:09:28 Debug: Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
2014-11-13 12:09:28 Debug: Origin:http://localhost:9000
2014-11-13 12:09:28 Debug: User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 7_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11A465 Safari/9537.53
2014-11-13 12:09:28 Debug: Authorization:Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImFkbWluX253In0.NszPvZauAWRq5GqqS70l_0UTkTCJoHkRWM8ZM8O0-fk
2014-11-13 12:09:28 Debug: Referer:http://localhost:9000/
2014-11-13 12:09:28 Debug: Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
2014-11-13 12:09:28 Debug: Accept-Language:de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Authorzation` header is a special case, PHP doesn't expose it via the `$_SERVER` superglobal, which is where `CakeRequest::header()` retrieves the headers from, and if I'm not mistaken PHP only supports the `Basic` and `Digest` auth schemes anyways.

If it where a valid digest auth header, then PHP would make its value available via `PHP_AUTH_DIGEST`, see **http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php**, but that wouldn't work with `CakeRequest::header()` too, as it prepends `HTTP_` to the name.

Long story short, you cannot access the `Authorization` header via `CakeRequest::header()`, so if you're on Apache, use `apache_request_headers()` instead, or in case you have control over the request, use a custom header instead.

Including `apache_request_headers()` in `CakeRequest::header()` might be something for a feature request.